# searching is not work when reload bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap table to show my data and I made an edit button to update the details of a row using ajax. Now I want to update the contents of the table without reloading full page. I tried by using this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax/show-data.php",
  data: "gid="+ allVals + "&msg="+ tex,
  success: function(result) {
    $("#gname").load(window.location + '#gname'); //gname id of the table
  },
});
```

The Problem is that when I'm using the code above the code isn't working properly. Please Help me.

Comment: delegate your other events

Comment: Thanks my problem is solved.

Comment: good for you :)